# Getting `nan` for variables when using gradient descent optimizer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to do something very similar to the "Getting Started" tutorial on the tensorflow homepage. However, I keep getting `nan` for my variables when using the gradient descent trainer used in the tutorial.

Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random

def generate_data(sample_count, slope, intercept, epsilon, min_x, max_x):
    xs = [random.uniform(min_x, max_x) for _ in range(sample_count)]
    ys = [slope * x + intercept + random.uniform(-epsilon, epsilon) for x in xs]
    return xs, ys

# Create Data
sample_count = 1000
slope = 3
intercept = 0 
epsilon = 20
min_x = 0
max_x = 100

xs, ys = generate_data(sample_count, slope, intercept, epsilon, min_x, max_x)

# Linear Model
initial_m = 1.
initial_b = 0.

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
m = tf.Variable(initial_m, tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(initial_b, tf.float32)
linear_model = m * x + b

# Loss Function
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - linear_model))

# Train Model
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
training_iterations = 100

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(training_iterations):
        sess.run(train, {x: xs, y: ys})

    results = sess.run([m, b])
    print('true m: {} b: {}'.format(slope, intercept))
    print('optimized m: {} b: {}'.format(results[0], results[1]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `reduce_mean` instead of `reduce_sum` (1), and/or decrease the learning rate.

(1) They call it "*mean* square error"

Comment: Oh ok, so I guess I am "overflowing" the floating point numbers with my sum? I switched it to mean, and still get nan, when I allow max_x to be 100. If I change it to 10, it works fine. Kind of weird.

Comment: @zrbecker You are not overflowing the sum per se. You are effectively using a HUGE learning rate.

Comment: How do I figure out what learning rate I should use? Why is that one "HUGE"? The Getting Started Tutorial used it, so I figured, maybe for what I was doing, that was a good one to use. lol.

Comment: @zrbecker  **"How do I figure out what learning rate I should use?"** Typically, it's empirical, and/or based on experience. Although in your particular case, you could find the optimal lr analytically.